# How to sort list based on subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to  sort the teams data according to membership, I have written sql in following way and I'm not sure how I can add sorting according to the number of members.Please can you guys help.

```
SELECT
    t.name,
    t.description,
    ARRAY (
        SELECT
            json_build_object('id', tm.id, 'owner', tm.owner, 'person', json_build_object('id', p.id, 'name', p.name, 'email', p.email))
        FROM
            membership tm
            INNER JOIN person p ON p.id = tm.personId
        WHERE
            tm.teamid = t.id) AS membership
    FROM
        team AS t
    WHERE
        t.id = 1;
```

So above code gives me following data

```
 [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'Coco cola',
    description: 'drink',
    membership: [{
      id: 12,
      owner: false,
      person: {
        name: 'john deo',
        'email': 'email@hotmail.com'
      }
    }, {
      id: 122,
      owner: false,
      person: {
        name: 'peter deo',
        'email': 'peter@hotmail.com'
      }
    }]
  }, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'fanta',
    description: 'drink',
    membership: [{
      id: 13,
      owner: false,
      person: {
        name: 'rose',
        'email': 'rose@hotmail.com'
      }
    }, {
      id: 172,
      owner: false,
      person: {
        name: 'david',
        'email': 'david@hotmail.com'
      }
    }]
  }
 ]
```

My tables are:

```
team (id, name, description)
membership (id, owner, teamId, personId )
person (id, name, email)
```

What I want to do is to sort the teams according to number of membership.

Comment: Add an `order by` in your sub-query

Answer (score 0):

Just add an `ORDER BY` to the outer query.  In this case, I'm going to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT t.name, t.description,
       (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(json_build_object('id', tm.id, 'owner', tm.owner, 'person',
                                           json_build_object('id', p.id, 'name', p.name, 'email', p.email)
                                          )
                        )
        FROM membership tm JOIN
             person p
             ON p.id = tm.personId
        WHERE tm.teamid = t.id
      ) membership
FROM team t
WHERE a.id = 1  -- this is invalid because `a` does not refer to anything
ORDER BY (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM membership tm WHERE tm.teamid = t.id) DESC;
```

I happened to write this using `ARRAY_AGG()` rather than `ARRAY()` with a subquery.  It think they are equivalent.